# Form POST submit "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, post, submit

I have no idea where I've made a mistake. I've been trying to solve this problem for hours but can't figure it out... 
I'm getting `HTTP Status 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.` while submiting the form with list of objects with some checkboxes to each of the objects.
Heres some of the code:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/panel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminPanel(Locale locale, Model model, Form form,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    FormWrapper wrapper = getFormWrapper();
    model.addAttribute("listOfObjects", wrapper);
    model.addAttribute("allCategories", dao.getCatsList());
    return "WEB-INF/views/index/admin/home";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/saveAdmin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="listOfObjects") FormWrapper listOfObjects) {
    return "redirect:../index.html"; 
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<form:form modelAttribute="listOfObjects" method="POST" action="/admin/saveAdmin">
  <c:forEach var="myObject" items="${listOfObjects.list}" varStatus="loop">

    <form:checkboxes items="${allCategories}" path="list[${loop.index}].selectedCategories" itemLabel="name"/>

  </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit" value="saveTest"/>
</form:form>
```

FormWrapper:

```
public class FormWrapper {
private List<Form> list;

public List<Form> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<Form> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

}
```

Category:

```
 public class Category{
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long categoryId;
 private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Category){
        return getCategoryId().equals(((Category)obj).getCategoryId());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I tried to change the model attribute adnotatnion to `RequestParam` , but in such case , my object is always null

Comment: Need to see your FormWrapper definition

Comment: What type does `dao.getCatsList()` give?

Comment: List<Category> , I've updated question with implementation of Category

Answer (score 1):

Is it because, the FormWrapper class do not have a property "selectedCategories".
I tried removing the "selectedCategories"
Then the form was submitted successfully.

```
<form:checkboxes items="${allCategories}" path="list[${loop.index}]" itemLabel="name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your jsp correctly but this problem occurs when something in the jsp form does not match with the parameters you're handling at the controller.

Are you sure that "path" variable below is ok?

```
<form:checkboxes items="${allCategories}" path="list[${loop.index}].selectedCategories" itemLabel="name"/>
```